# PayPal Sales Tax Setting on the Account is Ignored When Creating an Order via REST API

Tags: python, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

How can I let PayPal determine whether sales tax is applicable to a sale and adjust the total accordingly when the order is created via their REST API?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24639720/pp-rest-api-charge-tax-and-shipping-without-sending-address) which simply asks how to accomplish this, but I believe the answer to *that* question can be found [here](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/helpcenter/helphub/article/?solutionId=FAQ2932&topicID=FEES_US&m=TCI), which instructs the account owner to update their sales tax settings.

This has been done, however the total displayed (and charged) on PayPal's website is not updated when a user with an in-state address logs in/checks out.

As per the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/) I'm creating an order by sending the following data structure using the Python SDK that is [linked to](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK) in the docs:

```
{
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": 'http://www.myreturnurl.com',
        "cancel_url": 'http://www.mycancelurl.com'
    },
    "transactions": [{
        "item_list": {
            "items": cart_contents
        },
        "amount": {
            "total": order_total,
            "currency": "USD",
            "details": {
                "subtotal": subtotal,
                #"tax": "0.00",
                "shipping": shipping
            }
        },
        "description": "This is the payment transaction description."
    }]
}
```

I would expect commenting out the `tax` key would allow the PayPal account settings to determine and apply tax. The answer to [this question](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Merchant-services-Archive/Collecting-Sales-Tax-from-in-state-residents/td-p/318906) on PayPal's Community Help Forum lead me to believe that by sending `0.00` tax, I was overriding the sales tax setting of the profile, and by removing this from the submission, the account settings would be applied.

This does not seem to be the case. I cannot get the account's sales tax settings to be applied to an order. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out, PayPal does *not* support tax calculation via profile setting using their REST API (as of the time of writing).

From a correspondence with a Tier 2 PayPal Merchant Technical Support Representative:

> Running through the Rest playground using my credentials, I seemed to run across the same behavior. I then tried using ExpressCheckout calls with the same results. When I tried using PayPal standard (buy now button) the tax calculated when I got to PayPal.
>
> I asked around and was told the profile only works with standard and you need to pass the tax over if using different methods as the functionality wasn't included at this point.